# UI Issues: Border Radius, Button Functionality, Alignment, and Color Theory Implementation, Enter_container radius

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, border-radius, right-align

I want to align the borders where it says 'Entrar,' and the 'Entrar' button also needs to log in if the user exists. The 'Novo Aqui?' button doesn't redirect to another page called 'Cadastro' and doesn't look like a button; when someone hovers over it, it only changes the color of the letters. I want it to redirect to another page, which in this case would be 'Register,' and use color theory to change the color when the user hovers over it.

I tried to align the 'Novo Aqui?' button to the right, but I got lost because there are too many divs and rules. On this button, I tried to redirect to another page like a button, but it still didn't look like a button; it appeared as an unformatted redirect link. I tried to round the right corner border, but I didn't succeed. I attempted to use !important, but it was unsuccessful. The 'Entrar' button doesn't have rounded borders on the left, only on the right, and it should log in if a user with that email and password exists.

I tried to align the 'Novo Aqui?' button to the right, but I got lost because there are too many divs and rules. On this button, I tried to redirect to another page like a button, but it still didn't look like a button; it appeared as an unformatted redirect link. I tried to round the right corner border, where the 'enter_container' is located, but I didn't succeed. I attempted to use !important, but it was unsuccessful. Everything was written in Portuguese (pt-br): 'Entrar' is the same as 'Sign in,' 'Novo Aqui?' is the same as 'New Here?'

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './Entrar.module.css';

const Entrar = () => {
  const [dados, setDados] = useState({
    email: '',
    senha: '',
  });

  const [erro, setErro] = useState("");

  const handleMudar = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    setDados({ ...dados, [input.name]: input.value });
  };

  const handleEnviar = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const url = 'http://localhost:5555/autenticarRotas';
      const { data: resultado } = await axios.post(url, dados);
      localStorage.setItem('token', resultado.token);
      window.location = "/";
    } catch (erro) {
      if (
        erro.response && erro.response.status >= 400 &&
        erro.response.status <= 500
      ) {
        setErro(erro.response.data.message);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.entrar_container}>
      <div className={styles.entrar}>
        <div className={styles.left}>
          <form onSubmit={handleEnviar} className={styles.form}>
            <h1>Entrar</h1>
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              name='email'
              onChange={handleMudar}
              value={dados.email}
              required
              className={styles.input}
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Senha"
              name='senha' // Changed to 'senha' from 'password'
              onChange={handleMudar}
              value={dados.senha}
              required
              className={styles.input}
            />
            {erro && <div className={styles.erro_msg}>{erro}</div>}
            <div className={styles.button_container}>
              <button type="submit" className={styles.entrar_btn}>
                Entrar
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.button_container}>
              <button className={styles.novo_aqui_btn} onClick={() => navigate("/cadastrar")}>
                Novo Aqui?
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Entrar;

    /* Create all the fields components that exist in the file Entrar.jsx */
/* General Styles */
.entrar_container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  /* Left Side - Introduction */
  .left {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3bb19b, #318994);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  
  .left h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  /* Right Side - Registration Form */
  .right {
    flex: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    /* Changed to top-left */
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    /* Changed to bottom-left */
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  
  .right form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  /* Input Styles */
  .input {
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  
  .form input {
    color: black;
  }
  
  /* Error Message Styles */
  .erro_msg {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: #f34646;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .button_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  /* Button Styles */
  .entrar_btn {
    color: white;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; /* Rounded edges */
  }
  
  .entrar_btn:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
  }
  
  .novo_aqui_btn {
    color: white; /* Text color is white */
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; /* Rounded edges */
  }
  
  .novo_aqui_btn:hover {
    color: #0056b3;
  }
```

Comment: I fixed the buttons, changed the color when a mouse pass over the button, made the border radius. 
But the problem now is that I cannot save the user in the database, when I try to register a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the UI problem of the buttons being more specific here is the code below

```
Entrar.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './Entrar.module.css';
import axios from 'axios';

const Entrar = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      navigate('/');
    }
  }, [navigate]);

  const [dados, setDados] = useState({
    email: '',
    senha: '',
  });

  const [erro, setErro] = useState("");

  const handleMudar = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    setDados({ ...dados, [input.name]: input.value });
  };

  const handleEnviar = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const url = 'http://localhost:5555/autenticar/';
      const { data: resultado } = await axios.post(url, dados);
      localStorage.setItem('token', resultado.token);
      window.location = "/entrar/home";
    } catch (erro) {
      if (
        erro.response && erro.response.status >= 400 &&
        erro.response.status <= 500
      ) {
        setErro(erro.response.data.message);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.entrar_container}>
      <div className={styles.entrar}>
        <div className={styles.left}>
          <form onSubmit={handleEnviar} className={styles.form}>
            <h1>Entrar</h1>
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              name='email'
              onChange={handleMudar}
              value={dados.email}
              required
              className={styles.input}
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Senha"
              name='senha' // Changed to 'senha' from 'password'
              onChange={handleMudar}
              value={dados.senha}
              required
              className={styles.input}
            />
            {erro && <div className={styles.erro_msg}>{erro}</div>}
            <div className={styles.button_container}>
              <button type="submit" className={styles.entrar_btn}>
                Entrar
              </button>
              <Link to="/entrar/cadastrar">
              <button className={styles.novo_aqui_btn}>
                Novo Aqui?
              </button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Entrar;

Entrar.module.css
/* Create all the fields components that exist in the file Entrar.jsx */
/* General Styles */
.entrar_container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* Left Side - Introduction */
.left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3bb19b, #318994);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.left h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* Right Side - Registration Form */
.right {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  /* Changed to top-left */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  /* Changed to bottom-left */
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.right form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Input Styles */
.input {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.form input {
  color: black;
}

/* Error Message Styles */
.erro_msg {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #f34646;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

div .entrar_btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #3bb19b;
}

.entrar_btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(51, 49, 47);
}

div .novo_aqui_btn {
  background-color: #3bb19b;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.novo_aqui_btn:hover {
  background-color:  rgb(51, 49, 47);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i'm getting from your question is that you want to change the "border-radius" and the "text" of a button on :hover

```css
button {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 28px
}

button:hover span {
  display: none
}

button:hover {
  border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;  
  background: red
}

button:hover:before {
  content: "Reply!";
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>
    Button
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: I want to align the button where it says New Here? to the right of the Enter button, which both look like a button and when someone hovers the mouse over it, it changes color to a matching color. The enter button already changes color but it would have to change the color too as it only looks like a button when the mouse is hovered over it. Actually, doesn't this look like a New Here button? because if when you hover the mouse over it it looks like a link, it should look like a button. And I have to leave the edges on the right side of the entrance rounded

Comment: Oke i see that english isn't your first language. I would suggest to make a list on what you want to do with your button from a to b

Comment: 1 - Rounded edges for the "enter_container."
2 -"Entrar" button color should harmonize with the color scheme, following color theory.
3 - "Entrar" button should have rounded edges on both sides.
4 - "Novo Aqui?" button, placed below the form, should feature rounded edges like the "Entrar" button.
5 -When clicking the "Novo Aqui?" button, it should redirect to the "Cadastrar" page and have a hover effect with a color matching the color theory.
6 -The "Entrar" button should log in users if a matching email and password combination is found.

Comment: I managed to fix it by rounding the edges where div_container is located, and I was able to place 'New Here?' on the right side. But that's it for now. In the div what was needed was to use border-radius instead of border-radius-top-right, the Novo Aqui? I jsut removed this before the button <div className={styles.button_container}>